# "Духовность — это слово часто ассоциируется (...)". Тире или запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

"Духовность — это слово часто ассоциируется с религией и ритуалами".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Только не запятая.

**Духовность** - это именительный темы. Чаще всего после него ставится знак конца - точка, восклицательный знак, многоточие: Москва, Сибирь. Два эти слова звучали именем страны (Тв.); Слово! Язык! Об этом нужно писать не короткие статьи, а страстные воззвания к писателям (Пауст.); Журавли... Заваленный работою — вдалеке от сумрачных полей, я живу со странною заботою — увидать бы в небе журавлей (Сол.); Холодные и дикие просторы!.. Как давно были сказаны впервые эти слова и были ли они сказаны кем-то?.. (Расп.).

**Однако при именительном темы, более тесно связанном с основным предложением, в котором имеется личное или указательное местоимение в качестве слова-отсылки, ставится тире**:

*Тягач — он как танк, только без башни (газ.); Марченко — тот был человек, золотой человек (Каз.); Дорога в дождь — она не сладость, дорога в дождь — она беда (Евт.).*

У нас есть **указательное местоимение**, значит, ставим **тире.**

У Лопатина есть примечание:

Допустимо используемое в практике печати и написание с запятой: Врач, он ведь тоже не Бог (Бык.); Судьбы человеческие, они — каждая сама по себе, хотя мы вроде бы сообща и всё у нас должно быть общим (Аст.); Наташа, та знала, что за человек ее тетя (Бит.).

Но у нас есть указательное местоимение ЭТО, а оно требует всё-таки тире.

Answer (score 1):

**Ни тире и не запятая.**

Если просто поставим тире, то ***это*** будет читаться как связка, например: *Духовность — это совокупность проявлений духа в мире и человеке.* Поэтому предложение нужно редактировать.

Варианты оформления:

(1) Духовность — это слово, которое часто ассоциируется с религией и ритуалами.

(2) Что такое духовность? Это слово часто ассоциируется с религией и ритуалами.

(3) Духовность... Это слово часто ассоциируется с религией и ритуалами.